# Show xticks with specified interval on pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

When I plot the folowing DataFrame named `df`, I got this figure.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1 for _ in range(20)]]).T
df.index = ["{}:00:00".format(x) for x in range(20)]
df.plot()
```

[image]

I'd like to show `xticks` every two or three rows, i.e., 0:00, 2:00, 4:00,... because every 5 interval looks too large.

Is it possible to show xticks with specified interval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your index is a bunch of strings, not actual dates.

If you use dates, pandas can smarter about what it tells matplotlib to do:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'A': range(20)}, index=pandas.date_range('2012-01-01', freq='1H', periods=20))
df.plot()
```

[image]

That said, if you still don't like pandas' choices, there are many many questions SO about placing ticks in matplotlib. Here is one of them:
[Frequency and rotation of x-axis labels in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28062745/frequency-and-rotation-of-x-axis-labels-in-matplotlib/28063506#28063506)